# How to change marker size/scale in legend when marker is set to pixel

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I am scatter ploting data points with a very small marker (see screengrab below). When I use the very small marker ',' the legend is very hard to read (example code taken from [here](https://intoli.com/blog/resizing-matplotlib-legend-markers/)).
(Python 3, Jupyter lab)

[image]

How can I increase the size of the marker in the legend. The two versions shown on the above mentioned site do not work:

```
legend = ax.legend(frameon=True)  
for legend_handle in legend.legendHandles:  
    legend_handle._legmarker.set_markersize(9)
```

and

```
ax.legend(markerscale=6)
```

The two solutions *do* however work when the marker is set to '.'.
How can I show bigger makers in the legend?

**Sample Code from [intoli.com](https://intoli.com/blog/resizing-matplotlib-legend-markers/):**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(12)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for i in range(5):
    mean = [np.random.random()*10, np.random.random()*10]
    covariance = [ [1 + np.random.random(), np.random.random() - 1],  [0, 1 + np.random.random()], ]
    covariance[1][0] = covariance[0][1]  # must be symmetric
    x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, covariance, 3000).T
    plt.plot(x, y, ',', label=f'Cluster {i + 1}')

ax.legend(markerscale=12)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get 1 pixel sized markers for a `plot` by setting the markersize to 1 pixel. This would look like

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker='s', markersize=72./fig.dpi, mec="None", ls="None")
```

What the above does is set the marker to a square, set the markersize to the ppi (points per inch) divided by dpi (dots per inch) == dots == pixels, and removes lines and edges.

Then the solution you tried using `markerscale` in the legend works nicely.

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(12)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for i in range(5):
    mean = [np.random.random()*10, np.random.random()*10]
    covariance = [ [1 + np.random.random(), np.random.random() - 1],  [0, 1 + np.random.random()], ]
    covariance[1][0] = covariance[0][1]  # must be symmetric
    x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, covariance, 3000).T
    plt.plot(x, y, marker='s', markersize=72./fig.dpi, mec="None", ls="None", 
             label=f'Cluster {i + 1}')

ax.legend(markerscale=12)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How did you determine the number of points per inch to be 72? Seems that would be dependent on final screen resolution showing the plot.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this discussion](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Why-pixel-marker-size-is-4-pixels-td27332.html), the `markersize` has no effect when using pixels (`,`) as marker. How about generating a custom legend instead? For example, by adapting the first example in [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html), one can get a pretty decent legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

np.random.seed(12)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for i in range(5):
    mean = [np.random.random()*10, np.random.random()*10]
    covariance = [ [1 + np.random.random(), np.random.random() - 1],  [0, 1 + np.random.random()], ]
    covariance[1][0] = covariance[0][1]  # must be symmetric
    x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, covariance, 3000).T
    plt.plot(x, y, ',', label=f'Cluster {i + 1}')



##generating custom legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
patches = []
for handle, label in zip(handles, labels):
    patches.append(mpatches.Patch(color=handle.get_color(), label=label))

legend = ax.legend(handles=patches)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output would look like this:

[image: result of above code]